# Add new element to mongoDB document array only if a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoDB document structure:

```
Game = {
  _id: 'randomObjectId',
  players: [Array of players ObjectIds],
  maxPlayers: 2,
  status: 'created' (or 'fully-booked')
}
```

When a new player joins the game I want to add him to the players array and change the `status` of the game to `fully-booked` only if this condition is met: `players.length < maxPlayers`.

To recap:

- Check inside the DB(using the query) if `players.length < maxPlayers`;
- If yes update the document
- If no send back an error response (optional)

Without this check it's easy to make the query using:

```js
Game.findByIdAndUpdate('randomObjectId', {
  $addToSet: {
    players: 'playerObjId'
  },
  gameStatus: 'fully-booked'
}, {
  new: true
})
```

What I don't know is how to add this condition to this (or other type of) query.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your condition is broken, btw. If implemented as requested, it'd mark a game as "fully booked" when the game gets its first player (1 of 2). I suggest you separate marking as "fully booked" from adding players to the game.

Comment: And to your general question, "how do I add conditions to updates", I'd use `findAndModify` here.

Comment: Please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set

Comment: @AlexBlex: aggregation pipeline's `$set` is irrelevant here, though? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the pipeline $set makes it possible to do conditional update with  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#mongodb-expression-exp.-cond operator.

Comment: @AlexBlex but this update is only in-memory, to an ephemeral object that is being built for response.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  how come? I mean what in the question made you thinking it's not a persistent update? Did you confuse it with Daniel's question? =)

Comment: @AlexBlex: the question asks for a way to persist the update. But the aggregation pipeline operator `$set` does not do that, does it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah, I get where the confusion comes from. You can use a subset of aggregation pipeline stages in update operations since v4.2  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/  It's full-scale proper update with all writes that you would expect from a regular update.

Comment: @AlexBlex ah, cool! I'll play with it later today. Thanks!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev np, it's a nice toy to play =) The playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/cRaHp7LaU1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try an aggregation pipeline update like the following. however, if already fully booked, the command will return a `null`. also note that if you try to add a player id that already exists in the array, it won't be added.

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: someObjectId,
        $expr: {
            $lt: [{ $size: "$players" }, "$maxPlayers"]
        }
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                players: { $setUnion: ["$players", [newPlayerObjectId]] }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                status: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $lt: [{ $size: "$players" }, "$maxPlayers"] },
                        then: "created",
                        else: "fully-booked"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    {
        returnNewDocument: true
    })
```

Comment: `$set` throws an error but the `$expr` in the first part prevents me from adding an extra player, so it works in the end. Thanks

Comment: @GabrielLupu works for me without an issue. see here: https://streamable.com/linm5c that is in mongo shell though. i'm not sure if mongoose has support for pipeline updates.